# How to keep array fields in PostgreSQL jsonb

Tags: postgresql, json, array

It seems that PostgreSQL (12+) cannot keep the PostgreSQL array type in jsonb objects. If a PostgreSQL array is stored in a jsonb, it seems that it's converted to a jsonb array.

For example, given the following array:

```
=> SELECT ARRAY['world'];
  array  
---------
 {world}
(1 row)
```

If one stores it into a jsonb field and then extract that field as a string:

```
=> SELECT (jsonb_build_object('location', ARRAY['world'])::text::jsonb)->>'location';
 ?column?  
-----------
 ["world"]
(1 row)
```

, the output isn't a PostgreSQL array (or string representation of an array) anymore.

The array's type seems to have been **erased** when it's stored into the jsonb. So one cannot use the array as it is anymore.

For example, the [format_x()](https://pgxn.org/dist/format_x/doc/format_x.html) function/extension works correctly on simple types:

```
=> SELECT format_x('Hello %(location)s!', jsonb_build_object('location', 'world'));
   format_x   
--------------
 Hello world!
```

, but breaks down (produces incorrect result) on array types.

```
=> SELECT format_x('Hello %(location)L!', jsonb_build_object('location', ARRAY['world']));
      format_x      
--------------------
 Hello '["world"]'!
```

In above, the array is no longer represented as an PostgreSQL array, which breaks things if you use this to build a dynamic SQL.

My question is:

*Is there a way to store PostgreSQL arrays faithfully in JSONB objects?*

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to a text representation before storing it.  It looks like you tried that, but you put the cast in the wrong place.

```
SELECT (jsonb_build_object('location', ARRAY['world']::text))->>'location';
```

But you might need to cast back to text[] as it won't remember what it used to be:

```
SELECT ((jsonb_build_object('location', ARRAY['world']::text))->>'location')::text[];
```